# Matplotlib won't upgrade using pip

Tags: python, matplotlib, pip, upgrade, environment

I am trying to `upgrade` `matplotlib`. I'm doing this via `!pip` and it seems to work. When I check the list in the `IPython console`:

```
!pip list
```

It returns the latest version of `matplotlib`

```
matplotlib 3.0.2
```

But when I check the version in the editor it returns

```
2.2.2
```

The very first line in the text editor shows

```
 #!/usr/bin/env python3
```

When inserting `!which pip` and `!which python` into the `IPython` `console` it returns the following:

```
!which python = /Users/XXXX/anaconda/bin/python
!which pip = /Users/XXXX/anaconda/bin/pip
```

Comment: What is "the editor"? Whatever it is, it may use a different python environment than the one you installed matplotlib to.

Comment: Yeh, it seems silly to ask the question now. When I checked `!conda` list it returned 3 different `versions`. Is there a simply way to change `environment`?

Comment: If you use conda, you would get a list of all environments via `conda env list`. You would `activate` any of them and then `conda list` should show you the version you have installed in this environment. However, if you are inside IPython, you are already running a certain environment. Maybe better install outside of IPython, then activate the environment, then start the IPython of that environment.

Comment: Thanks. When you say 'outside' of IPython, where do you mean?

Comment: In your system bash, command prompt...

Comment: Thanks @ImportanceOfBeingErnest. So something like `!conda install` then `!conda activate 'my env'`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's because your pip is not linked with python binary you are using. If you are using python in the console, you can get path by `which python`. Try this -

```
python -m pip install matplotlib --upgrade
```

If it doesn't work, check your pip path with `which pip`. Then open it in editor and on very first line, there must be a shebang line showing a path. Replace that path with result of `which python`.

Comment: So `!which` pip returns `/Users/XXXX/anaconda/bin/pip` and the first line in editor is `#!/usr/bin/env python3`. Do I just remove `env python3?`

Answer (score 0):

Try `git pull` to update matplotlib to 3.0.2. Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

It could be possible that there are two separate matplotlib packages installed in two different locations, and the editor is finding the older version before the newer one. You can try using the `which matplotlib` to see the location of the package. Then review your path variable (`echo $PATH`) to make sure there are no other matplotlib packages on your machine. If there is more than one, I would recommend deleting any additional, duplicate packages. Alternatively, you could alter the path variable to exclude the additional matplotlib packages.